# Singapore Changi Airport: Is Terminal 4 connected Airside to other terminals

Tags: airports, sin

I am boarding a flight from Terminal 4 at Changi airport, where my friend is boarding flight from Terminal 2.

Is Terminal 4 is connected airside to other terminals, so that I can meet my friend after immigration? I know that T1, T2 and T3 is connected airside and used them before. T4 is newer and is further away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Terminal 4 is not connected to the Skytrain system linking the other terminals, there is a **free airside transit bus** connecting it to Terminal 2.  See details and map on the Changi site:

http://www.changiairport.com/en/transport/transfer-between-terminals.html

Update: So if I understand the situation correctly, you're starting your journey from Singapore?  If you don't have checked bags, I would recommend checking in online, going through Immigration at T2, meeting your friend, and then continuing onto T4.

Comment: It mentions requiring an onward boarding pass. Is it applicable for my case?

Comment: Will they let Anish go airside at terminal 2? It's not clear to me that they will.

Comment: @jpatokal Can I ?

Comment: @AnishSheela Yes, I've done it myself (not T2/4, mind you, but going through at T3 when I had a flight from T1).  Immigration doesn't care as long as you have a valid boarding pass.